# Aws Cognito fail to achieve uniqueness in pool for Oidc Microsoft Azure federated users

Tags: azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, saml

Aws Cognito cannot translate correctly incoming Oidc Microsoft Azure generated user_id (microsoft_).
Some chars in the  part are treated as capitals and other as lower case with no rule so fails in achieving uniqueness (based on email) when I am calling AdminLinkProviderForUser function.

With Saml connection is working correctly BUT saml doesn't work with accounts out of the current Azure active directory.

Comment: Hello @Skpan, Did you follow this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-oidc-idp.html to set up the Oidc Identity provider?

Comment: Hi Nishant, yes, I am able to connect using Oidc with Azure, the only black hole is the 'user_id' misunderstanding of Cognito, that doesn't allow me to link users correctly (as new 'sub' value is created for each user even they seem to be connected) so doesn't allow me to achieve uniqueness.

Comment: Thank You for the explanation, Let me check this and get back to you.